# How to take array object from the array object based on the highest value by a column in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array, and each element of the array has a priority element. Based on the maximum priority value how can we generate the new array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Main Category 1
            [updated] => 2020-01-14 14:13:30
            [priority] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Main Category 2
            [updated] => 2020-01-14 17:19:35
            [priority] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Category 3
            [updated] => 2020-01-14 17:42:23
            [priority] => 3
        )

)
```

Thus the highest priority value here 3. So, the result array will be like the following. Can you help me please. Thank you in advance.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Category 3
                [updated] => 2020-01-14 17:42:23
                [priority] => 3
            )

    )
```

Comment: Start with a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort your array by `priority` descending, and then make an array of the `[0]` element:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $b->priority - $a->priority; });
print_r(array($array[0]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Category3
            [updated] => 2020-01-1417:42:23
            [priority] => 3
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YHbVB)